# Average and Case in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, average

I am trying to generate a report and the following  code does not produce the desired results which gives me 2 lines rather than one.

The ScoreTypeID could have values of 22, 52, 3 or 4 .   if it is 22 or 52, I need the average and if not I need to show 0.  Any idea what may be the problem ?  Thanks.

```
  CASE WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID = 22 THEN avg(fas1.totalscore)  
       WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID = 52 THEN avg(fas1.totalscore)   ELSE 0    
  END  AS   'Total Score',
```

Comment: Can you post your full query?

Comment: ...and please tell us what **database system** (and which **version**) you're using. SQL is just the structured query language - used by a great many database systems. ...

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3):

I think in your full query, you are missing the `GROUP BY` clause, eg

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ....
WHERE   ..
GROUP BY FAS1.ScoreTypeID
```

Comment: I disagree because I did have the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
 coalesce(avg(CASE WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID in (22, 52) THEN fas1.totalscore end), 0) AS   'Total Score'
```

This takes the average when the score is 22 or 52.  If there are no values present, it returns NULL.  The coalesce turns the NULL into a 0.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it in the format you have chosen you could use:

```
CASE WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID IN (22,52) THEN avg(fas1.totalscore) ELSE 0
  END  AS   'Total Score',
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!