# AVG and CASE in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Average and Case in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935413/average-and-case-in-sql)

I am using SQL Server 2008 and  trying to generate a report and the following code does not produce the desired results which gives me 2 lines rather than one. 
The ScoreTypeID could have values of 22, 52, 3 or 4 . if it is 22 or 52, I need the average and if not I need to show 0. Any idea what may be the problem ? Thanks.

```
CASE WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID = 22 THEN avg(fas1.totalscore)  
    WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID = 52 THEN avg(fas1.totalscore)   ELSE 0    
END  AS   'Total Score',
```

Comment: post your result and your exact code

Comment: If you ask a question and it's not getting suitable answers, it's an indication that you need to *improve* your question - try adding more information, respond to requests for example input and output, etc. Then *edit* your existing question with this information. Don't just ask the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us rest of the query, in general this should work;

```
CASE WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID IN (22,52) THEN avg(fas1.totalscore) 
     ELSE 0 END AS 'Total Score',
```

Or ;

```
ISNULL( AVG( case when FAS1.ScoreTypeID in (22,52) then fas1.totalscore
      else null end), 0) as 'Total Score',
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what output you want. If just 1 row:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN FAS1.ScoreTypeID IN (22, 52) THEN fas1.totalscore
         ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Score',
```

If 2 rows: (1 row for 22, 1 for 52)

```
SELECT FAS1.ScoreTypeID, AVG(fas1.totalscore) FROM ...
WHERE FAS1.ScoreTypeID IN (22, 52)
GROUP BY FAS1.ScoreTypeID
```

Comment: Actually I am just looking for one row.  the code that you provided was very helpful.